# Dynamically scheduled tasks

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery, celerybeat

I successfully configured Celery on my Django app and tested it. The test run was successful, as shown by the following output:

`celery -A concentrApp call mytask      0016f381-ed04-4a44-8c7a-c091a66dce0a`

`[2023-06-17 13:46:28,465: INFO/MainProcess] Task mytask[0016f381-ed04-4a44-8c7a-c091a66dce0a] received [2023-06-17 13:46:28,477: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task mytask[0016f381-ed04-4a44-8c7a-c091a66dce0a] succeeded in 0.009182458000005056s: None`
`

Now, I would like to take this a step further and make the task dynamic.
My goal is to create an endpoint that accepts parameters such as time, and param, and then run the task every sunday-thursday in the given hour using the provided parameter. This will allow me to customize the task execution based on user input, and make it several times that the user want.

Thank you

Comment: You can use [django-celery-beat](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create database backed tasks.